# Angular - How To Organize CSS Overrides Across Components For The App

Tags: css, angular, sass

I'm relatively new to angular. In the process of converting a React app to Angular just for learning purposes. I have a parent component that has a button (Custom Button Component). This button when loaded in the parent should be hidden and on hover should show the button. So you probably get an idea that I have some CSS selectors related to the parent component that override the child CSS. First should be `display: none` and then on hover I change it to `display: flex`
So the first problem I encountered was that I could not override the child CSS from the parent CSS. After reading all kinds of posts I moved the CSS overrides from the parent CSS to the global stylesheet and also added `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to the child component.

Next thing I noticed is that the `align-items: center` was not working on the child. First thought I had that guess I have to add that part to the global styles also? but what I really need to know is that is this the norm in Angular? If yes, then some things don't make sense to me. These styles are really not global. They are only related to the parent component then it seems kind of weird to add those to the global stylesheet.

In regards to the `align-items` not aligning the child (custom-button), I believe that happens because of the extra div being added around the button. So how do you handle such situations?

[image]

Appreciate any advice/tips.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overwrite children CSS classes from the parent componet. this is the way:

Assuming your child component have this CSS

```
 .child-class {
     background-color: blue;
 }
```

When you use this component the background color will be blue. But if you want to change that color to RED. In the parent component where you want the change you need to do this:

In your parent component

```
:host {
     ::ng-deep{
       .child-class {
             background-color: red;
       }
     }
}
```

**:host**  this refers to the component's HTML tag (that is created by Angular, in your case the tag of the component that contains the **app-custom-button**). Also you can apply css to the component tag.

for example:

```
:host{
     width: 100vw;
     height: 100vh
}
```

And with **::ng-deep** you can overwrite ALL styles inside your compoent. Does not matter if is a style from your child compoenent, grandchild, great-great-grandson, etc... even if its a component from an external library.

So... For example you can have the "custom background color as blue" then in one component you can keep that color but in other component you can change the color to red and in other component you can change the color to green....

Comment: Thank you! I will try this out and if it works I will accept the answer. What is your suggestion about the flexbox align-items not taking effect on the child because of the extra div that gets added around the child (button)?

Comment: I imagine two ways. One is with :host you can apply styles to that extra div. OR in the parent component when you use your child component apply a class to that tag "<app-custom-button class="myClass">" and in the child component you can apply some styles to the button in order to adjust it to the container (that extra div). OR. you can change the selector in your custom-button.component.ts from "app-custom-buttom" to "[custombutton]" and in your parent component <button  custombutton></button> And in your child component only "add to the card" that will avoid the creation of the extra div.

Comment: ok thanks. So as for the general styles issue. I tried this and it did not work.
.collection-item {
:host {
    ::ng-deep{
      .custom-button {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}

You see anything wrong here?

Comment: that depends on your div hierarchy but you can try only with :host {
  ::ng-deep {
    .custom-button {
      display: none;
    }
  }
} removing ".collection-item" or by this way  :host {
  ::ng-deep {
    .collection-item {
      .custom-button {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

Angular have the concept of ViewEncapsulation. By default, the value is set to `ViewEncapsulation.Emulated` and the css you put in the component is specific to the component and only to this component. The CSS will not be applied to the child components.

You can switch to `ViewEncapsulation.None` and you will disable this behavior and **all the css rules in your css file** will be applied to **all** your components in the application, and maybe you don't want this behavior. That's why I advice you to leave this option.

The other option you got is to put your specific css rule in `src/style.css` (if you didn't modify the default path). All css rules put in this file will be applied for all the application and you can keep the ViewEncapsulation of your component.

For `align-items`, i think you are right : the app-custom-button is wrapping your button, so you need to set a `width: 100%` to your button, then eventualy resize your app-custom-button